# How can I step into a core java class method in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, java

Hi I am going to dig a little more in Java so I would like to see how the program executed in the core class. For example, I would like to know how `String.chatAt()` is implemented, so I set breakpoint and tried to step into with debug mode. But I failed, I set bp at the second line when the program hit it, I used step into it still continue to the third line.

```
String a = "1231231241241";
char b = a.charAt(0);
System.out.println(b);
```

I think it should go into the source and show "no source found" and then give me a chance to attach the source file, right? But why it cannot get in? I can only use `ctrl+right` click on a method to get into source and attach.

Comment: You should attach sources of JDK, i.e. tell eclipse where source JAVA files are.

Comment: Hi I have attached src.zip the problem is that I cannot STEP IN the code. It will directly go to the next line.

Comment: Try to press F3 on `charAt` function. Will it browse to source? If yes hen try to set breakpoint inside. Problems here mean that various components see different jars and sources, try to verify all versions.

Answer (score 5):

It might be that your Eclipse is not setup to run with JDK, it might run with JRE instead.
Check [this link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse.html).
Also, I might suggest you to try and use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for your Java projects management, it makes the life so much easier, when you get a grasp of it.

Comment: Thanks my friend, actually I have set to use jdk/jre already. I can set bp in source file but the program CANNOT stop in it. Besides, I still cannot step into a library methods.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, you have the "Step filtering" functionality activated.

When debugging, it can sometimes be a bit annoying when the debugger steps into trivial classes whose internals you were not really interested in. Because of this, you can configure "Step filters". Classes or packages that are added as step filters will be ignored by the "Step into" operation.

If you want to configure which classes/packages should be included in the step filter, you can go to: 
 `Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Debug --> Step Filtering` 
My guess is that you have a `java.*` package filter defined there, meaning that the debugger will never step into any class within a package which starts with "java". Uncheck this package filter if you want to be able to step into `java.lang.String`

Alternatively, if you want to activate/deactivate step filtering completely, you can do this by clicking the `Use step filtering`  button in the debug view, as shown below:

[image: Toggling step filtering]

Answer (score 2):

To be able to look at the code of libriaries you are using in your project you should configure your build path by attaching the soruces and JavaDoc.

[Source Lookup](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-editsourcelookup.htm)

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have attached the src.zip and I can look at the code with F3. The problem is that I CANNOT step into the source code (in src.zip) even I set bp. e.g. in charAt method. and the program wont stop at the bp in String.java

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you dont have the "Source Attachment" set. Go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. Select the JRE you use and click "Edit", then set the Source Attachment to the src.zip that comes with the jdk by selecting the jars and clicking "Source Attachment" :).
You can do this with all of the jars at the same time by selecting them via shift-click.

Answer (score 0):

for example in this **System.out.println("test")** piece of code if you want to step into System class just click on System  and click F3 you will be redirected to attach the source  code if you haven't already attached.Just attached the src folder of the jdk